# On MSVC why does the warning "unreferenced formal parameter" does not appear for std::string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, parameters, compiler-warnings, stdstring

I have a function with three unused arguments:

```
#include <string>

void Test(int b, std::string a, int c)
{
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling it on level 4 in Visual Studio 2017,  I get warnings for `b` and `c`:

> ```
> 1>consoleapplication2.cpp(8): warning C4100: 'c': unreferenced formal parameter
> 1>consoleapplication2.cpp(8): warning C4100: 'b': unreferenced formal parameter
> ```

Why don't I get the same warning for `std::string a`?

Comment: it looks like the fact that the destructor gets called prevents the warning.

Comment: I don't know that compiler, but it's likely because `a` has a non-default constructor, so there may be side-effects that occur when it's passed by value.  It may well be the same logic that prevents the compiler from complaining that a `std::lock_guard` is unused within a scope - the side-effects are important there!

Comment: Logic for ignoring warning when destructor is non-trivial is faulty, even if for some reason you would need variable just for a destructor it does not need to have a name. If name is specified and not mentioned, it still looks just as broken without trivial destructor.

Answer (score 4):

While I can't answer **why** it behaves like this, I noticed there is a pattern.

Looks like MSVC doesn't warn on the unused object as long as the destructor is not defaulted:

```
struct X {
    ~X();// = default;
};

void Test(int b, X x)
{

}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't warn about `x`, but if you uncomment the `= default` warning appears.

I am not sure if it is a feature (for example, considering the potential side effects of destroying an object) or an artifact of an analyzer.

Comment: Does a non-default copy-constructor also prevent the warning?  That would be consistent, as that's also invoked as a consequence of passing by value.

Comment: @TobySpeight much to my surprise, in the tests I have performed, non-default copy constructor didn't make a difference. Possibly because it is invoked on calling site, unlike the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

It is an implementation-dependent warning.

I have tested your codes on gcc and clang, both warn a, b, and c:

clang:

```
prog.cc:5:15: warning: unused parameter 'b' [-Wunused-parameter]
void Test(int b, std::string a, int c)
              ^
prog.cc:5:30: warning: unused parameter 'a' [-Wunused-parameter]
void Test(int b, std::string a, int c)
                             ^
prog.cc:5:37: warning: unused parameter 'c' [-Wunused-parameter]

void Test(int b, std::string a, int c)
                                    ^
3 warnings generated.
```

gcc:

```
prog.cc: In function 'void Test(int, std::__cxx11::string, int)':
prog.cc:5:15: warning: unused parameter 'b' [-Wunused-parameter]
void Test(int b, std::string a, int c)
          ~~~~^
prog.cc:5:30: warning: unused parameter 'a' [-Wunused-parameter]
void Test(int b, std::string a, int c)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
prog.cc:5:37: warning: unused parameter 'c' [-Wunused-parameter]
void Test(int b, std::string a, int c)
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

So, maybe it is just msvc's negligence.

Comment: The question is about why MSVC behaves in this specific way, and I'm not sure results from other compilres plus 'maybe it is just negligence' is an answer for that.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer to the question in any way.

Comment: First line is the answer: it's up to implementation to decide to warn or not to warn. It may be correct or may not be. Warnings from other compilers are given as extra information.

Comment: But the question is specifically why MSVC is inconsistent in whether it warns between different scenarios, which implies a desire for a more concrete answer than 'well, you are not actually required to get *any* warning' and a citation that *other* compilers produce *other* results.

Comment: Technically, this is the only one that actually has an answer: It's different because it was allowed to be (as opposed to a bug). They probably were looking for a _why_, and the best answer is a combo of the two current ones, but this in fact answers the question.